# Dynamic Dropdown menu - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

First of all, I am new to mysqli and prepare statements so please let me know if you see any error. I have this static drop down menu :
[image]

HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu sgray fade" id="menu">

<li><a href="#">Bike</a>
    <!-- start mega menu -->
    <div class="cols3">
        <div class="col1">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">bikes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">wheels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">helmets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">components</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">pedals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GPS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">pumps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bike storage</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
                <div class="col1">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">power meters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hydratation system</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">shoes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">saddles</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end mega menu -->
</li>
```

I want to make a dynamic dropdown menu. I managed to show the `$categoryName` and the `$SubCategoryName` with this function:

```
function showMenuCategory(){
$db = db_connect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM Category"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$categoryName,$description,$pic,$active);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
echo'<li><a href="#">'.$categoryName.'</a>
<!-- start mega menu -->
<div class="cols3">
<div class="col1">
<ol>';
$dba = db_connect();
$Subquery = "SELECT * FROM Subcategory WHERE CategoryId = '".$id."'"; 
$Substmt = $dba->prepare($Subquery);
$Substmt->execute();
$Substmt->bind_result($Subid,$CatId,$SubCategoryName,$SubDescription);
while($Substmt->fetch()) {
echo'
<li><a href="#">'.$SubCategoryName.'</a></li>';
            }
 echo'
  </ol>
</div>
   <!-- end mega menu -->
      </li>';
                 }
                  }
```

The only problem is that it returns all the subcategories on the the same  `<div class="col1">`:

[image]

what I would like to obtain is count the subcategories and if the result is more than 4 return the other items in the second and third column.

UPDATE***: thanks to the answer below now the menu looks like this:

[image]

thanks!

Comment: `hydratation`? `hydration`, perhaps?

Comment: @MarcB  thanks for that, I was not checking the correct spelling. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about try this?

**To explain further**

What is happening is that for every subcategory fetched, I increment a counter.  If that counter hits 4, it ends the `<UL>` and `<DIV>` and creates a new one which will represent the new column.

```
function showMenuCategory(){
$db = db_connect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM Category"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$categoryName,$description,$pic,$active);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
echo'<li><a href="#">'.$categoryName.'</a>
<!-- start mega menu -->
<div class="cols3">
<div class="col1">
<ol>';
$dba = db_connect();
$Subquery = "SELECT * FROM Subcategory WHERE CategoryId = '".$id."'"; 
$Substmt = $dba->prepare($Subquery);
$Substmt->execute();
$Substmt->bind_result($Subid,$CatId,$SubCategoryName,$SubDescription);
$count = 0;
while($Substmt->fetch()) {
echo'
<li><a href="#">'.$SubCategoryName.'</a></li>';
$count+=1;
if ($count == 4) {
    $count = 0;
    echo '</ol></div><div class="col1"><ol>';
}
            }
 echo'
  </ol>
</div>
   <!-- end mega menu -->
  </li>';
             }
              }
```

EDIT: Misunderstood the purpose of col1.  They all should be col1 and should work now.  If not, leave me a comment!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reset the count

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly! I don't understand why somebody downvote this answer, But this is the major problem here. People click -1 without explaining the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showMenuCategory(){
    $db = db_connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Category"; 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$categoryName,$description,$pic,$active);
    echo '<div class="cols3">';
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo'<li><a href="#">'.$categoryName.'</a>
        <!-- start mega menu -->
        <div class="col1">
        <ol>';
        $dba = db_connect();
        $Subquery = "SELECT * FROM Subcategory WHERE CategoryId = '".$id."'"; 
        $Substmt = $dba->prepare($Subquery);
        $Substmt->execute();
        $Substmt->bind_result($Subid,$CatId,$SubCategoryName,$SubDescription);
        while($Substmt->fetch()) {
            echo'<li><a href="#">'.$SubCategoryName.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo'</ol>';
    }
    echo '</div><!-- end mega menu --></li>';
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't even show anymore the category. thanks anyway.